# DropdownMenuItem not clickable android compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to display a dropdown menu in my App under TopAppBar.

When I click the dropdowm menu, the list is displayed, but nothing happens when I select an item from the list. Moreover the dropdown menu is not collapsing. It looks like I can't click anything in the app anymore. What am I missing?

```
val countriesList = mutableListOf<String>("India", "USA", "Canada", "Germany","Australia")



@Composable
fun CountrySelection() {

    // State variables
    var countryName: String by remember { mutableStateOf(countriesList[0]) }
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Row(
            Modifier
                .padding(24.dp)
                .clickable {
                    expanded = !expanded
                }
                .padding(8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) { // Anchor view
            Text(text = countryName,fontSize = 18.sp,modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp)) // Country name label
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = "")

            //
            DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false
            }) {
                countriesList.forEach{ country->
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        expanded = false
                        countryName = country
                    }) {
                        Text(text = country)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as i can check your Composable working as expected, can you provide some other context where you using it so it can help us to find out exact issue.

Comment: @Bhavin I found the issue. It seems on the emulator the compose dropdown menu is buggy. Thx

Comment: Related Bugs in Issue Tracker:
1. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211841590
2. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211996681
3. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211474319

As discussed in one of the comments in the the first of the three bugs, performing a Wipe Data on your emulator might help.